# Lumen routing bug: is_object($value) && is_callable($value)

Tags: php, lumen

Rather than using the string "@" format for specifying callbacks in routes

```php
$router->get('status', 'ApiController@status');
```

I'm trying to create a route in lumen using the array syntax for the callback

```php
$router->get('status', [ApiController::class, 'status']);
```

(which works in Laravel)

However, in Lumen  I get the error:

"Unable to resolve route handler."

Looking into the Lumen code, I see a check for the callback :

```php
if ($value instanceof Closure) {
    $callable = $value->bindTo(new RoutingClosure);
    break;
}

if (is_object($value) && is_callable($value)) {
    $callable = $value;
    break;
}
```

The `is_object($value) && is_callable($value)` seems weird to me.

So questions...

1. How should I specify the callback using php callback syntax? (I'd rather not use closures)
2. Do I need to use the `__invoke()` magic function on my controller, and if so, how should I specify that?
3. Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a bug, it's just not supported by the framework. The lumen framework uses arrays when you want to add named routes, as described in the documentation for [named routes](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) and [controllers](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers).

Comment: Thanks Kim, so how can a callback be an object too?

Comment: That check is a simple if statement looking for invokable controllers. It's an easier way than checking via reflections for example. Here's a quick little [demo](https://3v4l.org/1k9NP) on how it works.